# Expiring a User account after creation?

Tags: user

We have some files we need to give people access to for a short period of time (maybe 1 month) and we want their account to automatically be set to expire 1 month from when they register.

I was looking into some plugins like [Membership Pro](https://www.joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/membership-pro-joomla-membership-subscription.html) but it seemed like they set expiration for subscription accounts. We don't need to take payment at all. They just register for free, and an administrator approves their account and they can have access to the files/articles/etc for a short period of time and then the account should expire.

Does anybody use or know if any plugins are capable of this?

Comment: Not sure on plugin, but if you know PHP, a CLI script with a cron could do it fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have more, than one options:

**JUser BestBefore**:  https://www.innato.nl/offering/software-development/free-downloads-for-joomla/joomla-3-x-plug-ins#plugin_juser_bestbefore_j30

The others are **Community Builder with CB Auto Actions** - this one is commercial:
https://www.joomlapolis.com/component/sppagebuilder/?view=page&id=25&Itemid=1249

and **JUserPrune Business edition** (also comercial): https://www.innato.nl/offering/software-development/paid-downloads/joomla-3-x-plug-ins/juserprune-business-j3-detail.

Or yeah, you can write your own CLI script - it is relatively easy.
Hopefully this helps.